# "Список о деталях"

Tags: предлоги, грамотная-речь

"Предлог "о" колесом переехал русский язык" - слова Василия Аксёнова. Он приводил самый нелепый, на его взгляд, пример употребления предлога "о": "список о деталях". Слышу много примеров неправильного построения фраз с этим предлогом. Наиболее частая ошибка - "он (она) понимает о том, что...". Таких безграмотных конструкций много (не только с глаголом "понимает"), но сейчас вспомнить их не могу. Почему простая конструкция "он понимает, что..." вытесняется (в разговорном языке, по крайней мере) конструкцией "он понимает о том, что"? Можно ли дать этому языковому явлению объяснение? Если кто-нибудь помнит ещё какие-то примеры подобного употребления предлога "о", приведите примеры, если не трудно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Похожие ошибки связаны не только с этим предлогом. Их суть - в употреблении предлога после переходного глагола или образованного от него (либо этимологически с ним связанного) слова. Из повседневно встречающихся ошибок: "оплатите за проезд", "передавайте оплату за проезд" (вместо винительного падежа без предлога, либо слова "плата" вместо "оплата"). В случае списка (перечня) чего-либо отсутствие предлога тоже может быть связано с "глагольной" этимологией и винительным падежом после глагола: переписано (перечислено) что? ->  список (перечень) чего? Отсюда закрепление беспредложных форм, а ошибки связаны с отсутствием чутья к этому (косноязычием). Конечно, есть и случаи, когда употребление с предлогом отрывается от этимологии, становится нормой и допускается наряду с беспредложным вариантом (представление чего, представление о чём и т.п.).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Alex_ander!

Comment: Но началось то с "Слова о полку".

Answer (score 0):

Он много понимает о процессах, происходящих в домне.
Он много понимает о том что, происходит в домне.
Он много понимает, что происходит в домне. Мне режет слух.
Он понимает, что происходит в домне. А это не режет.
Мне кажется зависит от слов связанных с глаголом.